# Show subsection titles on beamer Warsaw theme!

Tags: beamer

In Beamer class (Warsaw theme) subsection titles don't show up on the header!
(section titles do normally).

What can i do to fix the problem?!
MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\section{section1}
\subsection{a}
\subsection{b}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\section{section2}
\subsection{c}
\subsection{d}
\subsection{e}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

an this is what i get[image]

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that demonstrates you problem. Normally subsection titles are displayed in the header of the Warsaw theme

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `\section` and `\subsection` outside of frames.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\begin{document}
\section{section1}
\subsection{a}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}
\subsection{b}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}
\section{section2}
\subsection{c}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}
\subsection{d}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}
\subsection{e}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]